# Should I be using anchors or buttons in the following codeblock?

Tags: html, button, anchor, semantic-markup

I am writing a web application and am trying to decide whether it would be more semantically correct to use buttons or anchors in the following example:

```
<ul id="parent-list">
    <li id="parent-1" class="parent-list-item" value="1">
        <ul class="child-list">
            <li value="OPTION1" class="">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="no-style-a">OPTION1</a>
            </li>
            <li value="OPTION2" class="">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="no-style-a">OPTION2</a>
            </li>
            <li value="OPTION3" class="selected-child-list-item">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="no-style-a">OPTION3</a>
                <span class="selected-child-span">✓</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="parent-2" class="parent-list-item" value="2">
        <ul class="child-list">
            <li value="OPTION4" class="">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="no-style-a">OPTION4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    ...etc

</ul>
```

Each time an anchor is pressed, an onClick handler is called and a query is issued to our backend to retrieve all of the data matching the corresponding filters. Once the query returns, the frontend is updated to display this new information. The page does not reload, the frontend is updated dynamically (using react/redux to handle state changes).

Is there any reason I should be using anchors instead of buttons here?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not linking anywhere, you shouldn't use a link.

That said, if you were writing [unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), you would be linking to a server-side fallback for when the JS failed in which case you should use links.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, buttons should be used.  A screen reader user, when they hear "button", will think that some action is going to be performed.  When they hear "link", then some kind of navigation will be performed.  It sounds like you are performing an action and not navigation.

If you plan on using `role="button"` on your `<a>` tags, remember to add a keyboard handler so the user can press the Space key on your link to activate it since a "button" element implies both the Space and Enter keys will work.  If possible, use a native `<button>` because then it'll be handled for you.

Answer (score 0):

> **the frontend is updated dynamically**
>
> Is there any reason I should be using anchors instead of buttons here?

**Does the focus move somewhere else ?**

- Yes : it's a link
- No : it's a button

If you use javascript to emulate a page change, then yes, you can use anchors as long as the user perceive a page change or move within the page.